# replace do not work even with inplace=True

Tags: python, pandas

Replace function failed to work even with inplace=True.

data:

> `0      245778 others
>   1      245778 others
>   2      245778 others
>   4      245778 others`

code:
`df.likes=df.likes.astype('str')
df.likes.replace('others','',inplace=True)`

Result:

> `0      245778 others
>   1      245778 others
>   2      245778 others
>   4      245778 others`

Expected Result:

> `0      245778 
>   1      245778 
>   2      245778 
>   4      245778`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without setting the `regex` flag to `True`, replace will look for an exact match.

To get a partial match, just use `df.likes = df.likes.replace(' others', '', regex=True)`.